# Is the any way to upgrade all the Mac apps, even third-party, all at once

Tags: applications, homebrew, mac-appstore, upgrade

I have been wondering if there is any way to upgrade simply ALL the Mac apps at once, even the third-party apps downloaded outside the Mac App Store.

I know that there is this Homebrew code snippet that allows you to upgrade many apps, but not all of them. For me, this just scans the apps I have downloaded through brew or from App Store.

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew cu --all --yes --cleanup && mas upgrade && brew cleanup
```

**However, what I am looking for is some sort of a terminal command or **FREE** app that goes through every single app on my computer and looks for databases for the most recent software version.**

I also know that **there is this MacUpdater app** that does this but it seems rather expensive.

**So, I would be interested to know if there is any completely free MacUpdater alternative or some even more comprehensive brew command that could update everything all at once.**

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91517/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-notified-of-updates-for-all-of-my-non-mac-app-store

Comment: Brew obviously can only update applications which have been installed via brew (it doesn‘t „scan“ the system, it just updates the packages/formulae previously installed).

Comment: Given the widely varying methods for updating, the disparate nature of the databases (if they exist and are accessible), and incalculable number of variables to account for, you're not going to find this all encompassing solution.  Updating software is a process, not a product.

Comment: Contacting hundreds of developers, maintaining channels of communications for them to notify the database, and then for the database to be available online to anyone. That's a lot of work for free.

Comment: MacUpdater is, to my mind, worth every penny.